# Сложение векторов лямбда-функцией

Tags: python-3.x, map, lambda

Вот мой код, который создаёт "матрицу" из тех векторов, что нужно сложить:

```
vectors_num = int(input("Enter number of vectors: "))
vectors_dim = int(input("Enter dimension of vectors: "))
vector_list = list()
for i in range (vectors_num):
    print("Enter your vector:")
    try:
        tmp = list(map(int, input().split()))
        if len(tmp) != vectors_dim:
            raise ValueError ("Vector dimension must be the same")
        vector_list.append(tmp)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Мне нужно сложить в одной строке при помощи функции map и лямбда-функции данные вектора. Пример:

```
vector_list =  1 2 3
               4 5 6
               7 8 9

result = 6
         15
         24
```

Без использования numpy и других сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fn(list):
return sum(list)


vector_list = [[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9]]

vector_list = list(map(fn, vector_list))
print(vector_list)
```

В одну строчку:

```
vector_list = [[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 8, 9]]

print(list(map(lambda list: sum(list), vector_list)))
```

Comment: Нет, это неверное решение. Мне нужно не координаты каждого вектора складывать, а соответствующие координаты всех векторов. В моём примере каждый вложенный список это вектор. В примере приведена матрица, где столбцы - вектора, а не строки. В вашем примере должен получиться итоговый вектор 1+4+7 = 12; 2 + 5 + 8 = 15; 3 + 6 + 9 = 18, итоговый вектор [12, 15, 18]

Comment: `[sum(a) for a in zip(*vector_list)]`